# If each vector in a set $S_1$ is in the span of a set $S_2$, and each vector in $S_2$ is in the span of $S_1$, then they have the same span?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone expand on this? My book says just this one line but I'd like a bit of a longer explanation so I can understand why this is the case.

Comment: @JMoravitz: I seen linear algebra and immediately thought we were talking about vector spaces.

Comment: Hint: Span(X)=Span(Span(X)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S_1\subseteq span(S_2)$ then it follows that $span(S_1)\subseteq span(S_2)$

To see why this is, recognize that any element in $span(S_1)$ can be written as a linear combination of elements in $S_1$, each of which since is an element of $span(S_2)$ can be written as a linear combination of things in $S_2$.

That is to say, any element in $span(S_1)$ can be written as a linear combination of linear combinations of things in $S_2$.  Thus, any element in $span(S_1)$ can be written as a linear combination of things in $S_2$ and is therefore an element of $span(S_2)$.

This proves that $span(S_1)\subseteq span(S_2)$.  The same argument can be applied in the other direction showing $span(S_2)\subseteq span(S_1)$ thus showing that the spans are equal.

Comment: So if every vector in S1 is in the span of S2, that's enough to prove that S1 and S2 have the same span? I don't need to also show that every vector in S2 is in the span of S1?

Comment: @dagny no, you also need every vector in $S_2$ is in the span of $S_1$ to prove they have the same span.  Since we know that is true though, and since the argument is identical for each half of the proof, we only need to mention that the argument is identical and save our breath.  We don't have to prove the same thing twice where the only difference is labels.

Answer (score -1):

Each vector in S1 is in the span of S2 so this is the span of S1 union S2. Similarly, the span of S1 is the span of hte union.